# How can I filter distinct values from one column in a Django queryset without PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django

So I have a database tracking certain Wikipedia edits. Under certain, desired, circumstances, the database may save the same edit multiple times to the db, with one column having different values.

I want to be able to make a queryset that removes duplicate rows based on the `rc_id` column, which is the same for duplicate edits. I don't care which of the duplicate rows is discarded because I only need the non-unique information.

If I were using a PostgreSQL database I could use the DISTINCT ON feature via `queryset.objects.filter(field=filter).distinct('rc_id')`. In MySQL, however, this feature is not available.

Other SO questions on this topic have been answered by telling people to use `.values_list('rc_id').distinct()`, however I want the result to still be a queryset for further filtering, not a values list. How can I do this at the queryset level, or if necessary, with a raw SQL query?

Comment: The return value from `values_list` is a QuerySet, and it supports `filter`. Can you show an example of specific code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Hmm. I did `ordered_queryset = queryset.order_by('-timestamp').values_list('domain', 'timestamp', 'username', 'page_title', 'edit_summary', 'rc_id').distinct()` and later `ordered_queryset.order_by('timestamp')[0].timestamp.date()` which worked fine before adding the `values_list` component but now raises the error `'tuple' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`.

Comment: I've just found the `named=True` option and everything is working now. Thanks for the nudge towards the answer!

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Håken Lid above, my solution was the following:

```
ordered_queryset = queryset.order_by(
    '-timestamp').values_list(
        'domain', 'timestamp', 'username', 'page_title', 'edit_summary', 'rc_id', named=True
            ).distinct()
```

To clarify, each of the values in the values_list is the same for duplicate edits, and I've left out the column which is unique. As such, this returns a queryset with correctly filtered rows.